# Installin Django on Pycharm using "pip install Django"

Tags: python

Good day,

I am struggling to install Django using "pip install Django" in pycharm,i get error message below:-

[
C:\Users\Briant\PycharmProjects\PyShop>pip install django
Collecting django
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443):
Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/94/9f/a56f7893b1280e5019482260e246ab944d54a9a633a01ed04683d9ce5078/Django-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing co
nnection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/94/9f/a56f7893b1280e5019482260e246ab944d54a9a633a01ed04683d9ce5078/Django-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443):
Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/94/9f/a56f7893b1280e5019482260e246ab944d54a9a633a01ed04683d9ce5078/Django-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing co
nnection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /packages/94/9f/a56f7893b1280e5019482260e246ab944d54a9a633a01ed04683d9ce5078/Django-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443):
Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/94/9f/a56f7893b1280e5019482260e246ab944d54a9a633a01ed04683d9ce5078/Django-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/94/9f/a56f7893b1280e5019482260e
246ab944d54a9a633a01ed04683d9ce5078/Django-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15
)"))

You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 0):

The `ReadTimeoutError` hints towards a failed connection to the server that pip tried to download Django from.

There are several possible causes. First, try updating pip as the dump suggests. If you have an active firewall or proxy, check if pip is allowed through. If all else fails, you can always clone Django from the git repository and ask pip to install it as detailled on [this documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/install/#installing-the-development-version).